# windows phone 7 app link to post

Tags: windows-phone-7, marketplace

what is the best url to post similar to iTunes preview for WP7 I have an app that I would like to advertise through my website and by mailing to friends

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this out.
[How to: Link to Windows Phone Marketplace Content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff967553%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

Comment: got it http://social.zune.net/redirect?type=phoneApp&id=abdbb952-944e-e011-854c-00237de2db9e